# PHPunit: Testing memory usage or running time in assert statements

Tags: phpunit

I know that phpunit provides memory usage and execution time during test, but is there a way to use these data within an assert statement?

For example, say for example I want to assert if the consumed usage is greater than or equal a specified memory or running time. I search the net as well as the phpunit manuals and can' get an exact information.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm thinking in a wrong direction, but why not try something like this?

```
class memTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testMemory() {
        $this->assertGreaterThanOrEqual(4194304, memory_get_usage());
    }
}
```

Just use your desired assumption specifier (here: [`assertGreaterThanOrEqual`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertGreaterThanOrEqual)) and check your desired value against [`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php).

In my case the output looks like this:

```
>phpunit unittests\memtest.php
PHPUnit 3.7.15 
F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 1.75Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) memTest::testMemory
Failed asserting that 1503768 is equal to 4194304 or is greater than 4194304.

mypath\memtest.php:5

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: This is a great idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To run asserts on execution time and used memory you can use [phpunit_stopwatch_annotations](https://github.com/usernam3/phpunit_stopwatch_annotations) package. It provides it's own TestCase class, which add support for special annotations (**@executionTime** and **@memoryUsage**) for your tests methods.

How to use [phpunit_stopwatch_annotations](https://github.com/usernam3/phpunit_stopwatch_annotations):

1. Extend your TestCase class from StopwatchAnnotations\TestCase

   `class ExampleTest extends \StopwatchAnnotations\TestCase`
2. Start using annotations by writing

   @executionTime **time_in_milliseconds**

   or

   @memoryUsage **memory_in_bytes**

   in docblock before your methods. Execution time and memory usage will be asserted automatically after each test.

Answer (score 1):

If any is interested here I rewrote the StopwatchAnnotaions into a Listener to allow the integration of assertions on memory usage and execution time here :

https://github.com/jclaveau/phpunit-profile-asserts

```
public function test_usages()
{
    ...

    $this->assertExecutionTimeBelow(100); // seconds
    $this->assertMemoryUsageBelow('1M');
}
```

Cheers